# failed to open stream, include(), what is causing this?

Tags: php, include

I was installing a script and got the following errors

> Warning: include() [function.include]: Unable to access
>   ../GameEngine/config.php in
>   /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/GameEngine/Admin/database.php on
>   line 20
>
> Warning: include(../GameEngine/config.php) [function.include]: failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/GameEngine/Admin/database.php on
>   line 20
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Unable to access
>   ../GameEngine/config.php in
>   /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/GameEngine/Admin/database.php on
>   line 20
>
> Warning: include(../GameEngine/config.php) [function.include]: failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/GameEngine/Admin/database.php on
>   line 20
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   '../GameEngine/config.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/GameEngine/Admin/database.php on
>   line 20
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Unable to access
>   ../GameEngine/Data/buidata.php in
>   /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/GameEngine/Admin/database.php on
>   line 21
>
> Warning: include(../GameEngine/Data/buidata.php) [function.include]:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/GameEngine/Admin/database.php on
>   line 21
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Unable to access
>   ../GameEngine/Data/buidata.php in
>   /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/GameEngine/Admin/database.php on
>   line 21
>
> Warning: include(../GameEngine/Data/buidata.php) [function.include]:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/GameEngine/Admin/database.php on
>   line 21
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   '../GameEngine/Data/buidata.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/GameEngine/Admin/database.php on
>   line 21
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/GameEngine/Admin/database.php:20)
>   in /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/include/multihunter.php
>   on line 29

this file is located in `http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/include/multihunter.php`

what is causing these errors? could it be because I haven't set some folder permissions? the file config.php does infact exist.

Comment: What is the absolute path of config.php?

Comment: if I was you, I would use require_once instead of include

Comment: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/GameEngine/config.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files doesn't exist on the given phat.

Here is what the error shows (check the double dots):

```
Warning: include() [function.include]: Unable to access ../GameEngine/config.php in /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/GameEngine/Admin/database.php on line 20

Warning: include(../GameEngine/config.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/GameEngine/Admin/database.php on line 20

/home/freetrav/public_html/travian/GameEngine/Admin/database.php <- This is the file doing the include
/home/freetrav/public_html/travian/GameEngine/GameEngine/config.php <- This file doesn't exist
```

Comment: okay so.. the double dots are directory up.. so remove double dots? wait no, the double dots take it out of the admin folder and point towards config folder

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your whole *GameEngine* folder in the *install* folder.

OR modify your *multihunter.php* file and add an extra "../" in your *include* statements.

Comment: there are like 50 scripts, that would mess all of them up, gotta find an another way

Comment: Can you post the "include" line in your multihunter.php file? Also try the edit I posted.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys, fixed it. the problem was that the file calling all other files, was inside two folders and not one, so you would have to call up-directory(..) twice. so i added another set of dots with a slash and it worked.

```
include("../../GameEngine/config.php");
include("../../GameEngine/Data/buidata.php");
```

ty +1 for everyone